# Can ,I work with neo4j database without installing it in my system and without installing it?

Tags: neo4j

I am working with neo4j desktop version.I have created a graph database with it And want to use it in my project (.net project & created in visual studio). Which file I should put in my project to access the graph i have created ?

Comment: What research have you done? You should have plenty of free time since you escaped from Shawshank.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to access your Neo4j instance via .NET, you will find the .NET drivers helpful. [Information on how to install and a demo project are available](https://neo4j.com/developer/dotnet/).